# OAuth2 Client Credential flow - What is the purpose of getting an access token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

With the OAuth2 Client Credential flow, there are 2 steps to making an authenticated request to an API:

1. Using the *client id* and *client secret*, make a request to the authentication server. Get a temporary (ie. 24 hour) access token.
2. Using the *access token* retrieved from step 1, make a request to the API. The API will validate with the authentication server that the access token is valid. If it is, then accept the request.

What I am not clear about is why does this flow make more sense than just passing the client id and secret to the API and then the API validating with the authentication server that the client id and client secret are valid?

In my specific case, the authentication server and API are owned by the same company.

Answer (score 1):

In many OAuth scenarios similar to yours (i.e. Auth Server and Resource API are same company) the resource server does not need to contact the Auth server to check if a token is valid. It may just verify the token was signed by the Auth server and then use the data directly from the token against an underlying data source thus saving a trip out to the Auth Server.

But if the client credentials are passed in to the API instead, it will need to connect to the authorisation server every time to verify the client credentials and scopes are still valid.

Also using bearer tokens over credentials in the request is probably a better call to make as soon you will be able to benefit from [Token Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_Binding)

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of using tokens rather than sending clientID and secret are:

- The secret is not being sent with every request. If if the token is compromised i.e. via MITM attack then it can only be used until it expires e.g. after 15 minutes. (btw, 24 hours token seems long but it may depend on the use case)
- The token can also include additional claims such as authorization scopes, etc.

With regards to the reply by iandayman, the client doesn't have to communicate with AuthServer every time to validate the token. The client can obtain the public key from the AuthServer, cache it and use it for validating the token and its claims. Most libraries would likely handle that for you.